# Wordpress: Using author metadata in href

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I want to use the user's twitter handle from the dashboard (i have the twitter plugin activated) in an `a` tag href. However, the php seems to be spitting out the user's handle away the href. Kind of complicated for me to explain but hopefully that helps. Below is an image showing where what is currently looks like. Note the 'the_user' up above the byline. I want that to be used in the href of the twitter icon.

[image: Example]

Here is the line of code i'm using in the template-tags.php file:

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
            echo '<table id="blog-author"><tr><td><span class="author-avatar">'.get_avatar($author_id).'</span></td><td><span class="byline">'. $byline.'</span></td>'
                    . '<td><a href="http://www.twitter.com/'.the_author_meta('twitter').'"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></span></td><tr></table>';
```

I presume it will be as simple as wrapping `the_author_meta('twitter')` in some function but i cannot work it out or find what i'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you have simply `the_author_meta('twitter');` on a page all by itself?

Comment: do you use the_author_meta('twitter') somewhere else in the page? the link with the_author_meta('twitter') contains "the_user" or not?

Comment: @TimRoberts the same exact thing happens.

Comment: @sam12 no I just use the_author_meta('twitter') in the href. The link does not contain "the_user" at all. It simply outputs http://www.twitter.com/

Comment: if you remove the_author_meta('twitter') from the url, "the_user" is still displayed on the page?

Comment: @sam12 no - removing the_author_meta('twitter') from the url removes "the_user"

Comment: and if you use get_the_author_meta instead? sorry i have no WP installed

Comment: @sam12 perfect that fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it was a missing `get_` that was causing the issue. I ran into the same thing often with ACF

Comment: @DB1500 no problem ;) for information: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/

Comment: yep @TimRoberts the_author_meta displays and get_the_author_meta returns